# Type of interpolation used with metpy interpolate_to_isosurface

Tags: interpolation, netcdf, metpy

I'm wondering what type of interpolation scheme is used when calling interpolate_to_isosurface from metpy ?

I'm trying to interpolate a numerical atmospheric model and a set of data from a satellite which are in 2 separate files with netcdf4 module.
With longitude and latitude as x and y, i'm trying to plot z (gas concentration) with numpy arrays.

Thing is, there is another dimension in those files which is level (=altitude) and they are different from file model and file satellite, that's the point of the interpolation. I need to use cressman interpolation and I can't find in doc if interpolate_to_isosurface can be done with this scheme.
Although I could directly use interpolate_to_grid and choose cressman, I don't know how to deal with the level dimension.

Finally, if anyone can redirect me to cressman scheme implementation doc on python, it would be great ! I can only find theoritical ones and I can't figure out how to translate that into code.

Respectfully,
Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

`interpolate_to_isosurface` uses a linear interpolation between vertical levels, it is not able to use any other interpolation.

MetPy's `interpolate_to_grid` supports many different interpolation schemes, including Cressman weighting, to generate a regular grid of data from irregularly-spaced points, but not doing any interpolation in the vertical direction.

The Cressman scheme in general is designed to use distance-dependent weighting to average multiple observations within a cutoff radius. It sounds like what you want is to do what `interpolate_to_isosurface`, but use the Cressman-scheme weights instead of the normal weights for linear interpolation. In that case I'd start with the [code](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/blob/879855e972c0bee5def1253190a81e202c0278fe/src/metpy/interpolate/grid.py#L311-L361) for `interpolate_to_isosurface`, but use the Cressman weights:

```
w = np.clip((radius**2 - delta_z**2) / (radius**2 + delta_z**2), 0, np.inf)
```

You'll need to do some algebra to turn the linear interpolation into something that looks like a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points).